# В чем фишка ServletConfig?

Tags: java, servlet

В чем фишка ServletConfig? Да я понимаю что он нужен что бы передать какие либо параметры в сервлет через дискриптор развертывания. Но зачем это надо? Ведь если мы изменим значение в дискрипторе развертывания, после того как сервлет уже запустился, значение в сервлете не изменится, нам нужно перезагружать его снова. Не проще ли определять эти параметры сразу же в сервлете?

Comment: @michael_best Прямо говоря, подобные правки обычно считают "незначительными" и отклоняют. Не знаю, видите ли вы моё уведомление (говорят, в случае отклонённых правок они не показываются)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A servlet configuration object used by a servlet container to pass information to a servlet during initialization.

Хм,насколько я понимаю,конфигурационный файл не так часто меняется.
Объясняю за "не проще ли определять параметры сразу в сервлете"

1. Много лишнего кода
2. Конфигурационный файл общий для всех
3. Поверьте,поменять что-то в "стандарте" проще нежели в говно коде.

Вот про последнее по-конкретней.
InitParameters дают вам гибкость,чтобы не лазить в быдло коде изменять параметры,которые вы допустим используете для доступа к БД,а сделать все по красоте.Ибо,я еще раз повторюсь :

> Конфигурационный файл на то и конфигурационный,что бы в одной строкой поменять один параметр,а этот параметр поменяется во всем вашем коде.